# the $\Vdash$ relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus, forcing

There is a lemma in Kunen's book Set theory edition Studies in logic 34:
lemma IV.2.30(5) $$p\Vdash\varphi \text{ iff }\neg \exists q\leq p[q \Vdash\neg\varphi].$$

This equivalence has by elementary formal logic $2$ parts:

$(p$ forces $\varphi$ **or** some extension forces $\neg \varphi)$ **and**
$(p\not \Vdash\varphi$ **or** no extension forces $\neg\varphi).$

**My question is** what metamathematicaly says the $2$nd conjunct :

$(p\not \Vdash\varphi$ **or** no extension forces $\neg\varphi).$

Can it be described around?
I simply do not understand its meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that "no extension of $p$ forces $\neg\varphi$" is by definition of the forcing relation equivalent to "$p$ forces $\neg\neg\varphi$." Intuitively, this should be equivalent to "$p$ forces $\varphi$," and if you believe this then the second conjunct is obvious. Also note that "$p$ forces $\varphi$" clearly implies "$p$ forces $\neg\neg\varphi$."

So the real content of the second conjunct is basically saying that we have double negation elimination in this context.

Comment: What do you mean by "real conjunct of the second conjunct" ?

Comment: @user122424 Fixed.

Comment: I think you have composed what I have decomposed before:$$p\Vdash\varphi \text{ iff }\neg \exists q\leq p[q \Vdash\neg\varphi].$$ What I meant by my question was, whether it may be justified this perse: $(p\not \Vdash\varphi$ **or** no extension forces $\neg\varphi)$?

Comment: @user122424 Yes, that's sort of my point - that your decomposition makes it more mysterious, not less.

Comment: BUT this decomposition is used in my OQ in an essential way. Do you think that I should rather forget about this decomposition?

Comment: @user122424 I don't see what your decomposition is *doing* for you - why are you interested in writing the expression like that? Not everything is easier to understand in disjunctive normal form. My claim is that you can understand it better once you write it equivalently as an implication, and then think about what that implication says.

Comment: @user122424 In fact, I think decomposing the original statement *at all* just makes it less clear: it's exactly saying that $p\Vdash\varphi$ is the same as $p\Vdash\neg\neg\varphi$.

Comment: My decomposition has its origins in propositional logic. I just meant by it that equivalence should be understood as a conjunction of two disjunctions. And hence we should justify and among other things consider both of them separately. What I lack is the imagination of the second conjunction.

Comment: BUT if your suggestion is to forget about it, I may be happy with it also.

Comment: @user122424 "equivalence should be understood as a conjunction of two disjunctions" But my point is that that isn't always true: just because a sentence *can* be written in one form, doesn't mean that it's *most intuitive* to write it in that form.

Comment: I'm fine with that. It was just a mind-boggling that second conjunct and asking about it was an attempt to catch it.